# playwright storageSession failing inside docker containers in gitlab pipeline

Tags: javascript, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, playwright

I'm trying to use playwright inside of docker containers in our Gitlab ci pipeline. I followed the playwright Authenticate documentation. Locally the tests works fine, no issues but in the pipeline it seems to fail as if the storageState doesn't exist so the routes stay protected in the tests and ultimately timeout (as well as logout button is disabled unless item named header has a token value assigned to it in localstorage and that fails as well so can safely assume there is no token in localstorage).

my playwright_tests/auth.setup.js

```
import { test as setup, expect } from '@playwright/test';

const authFile = 'playwright/.auth/user.json';

setup('authenticate', async ({ page }) => {
  // Perform authentication steps.
  await page.goto('/');
  await page.setViewportSize({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();
  await page.waitForURL('/login');
  await page.setViewportSize({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
  await page.getByLabel('Username').click();
  await page.getByLabel('Username').fill('user');
  await page.getByLabel('Password', { exact: true }).click();
  await page.getByLabel('Password', { exact: true }).fill('password');
  await page.getByLabel('Password', { exact: true }).press('Enter');
  // Wait until the page receives the cookies.
  //
  // Sometimes login flow sets cookies in the process of several redirects.
  // Wait for the final URL to ensure that the cookies are actually set.
  await page.waitForURL('/');
  // End of authentication steps.

  await page.context().storageState({ path: authFile });
});
```

my playwright.config.js

```
// @ts-check
const { defineConfig, devices } = require('@playwright/test');
// import process
const process = require('process');

/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 */
// require('dotenv').config();

/**
 * @see https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration
 */
module.exports = defineConfig({
  testDir: './playwright_tests',
  outputDir: 'playwright/test_results',
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: [
    [
      'html',
      { outputFolder: 'playwright_results/playwright_report', open: 'never' },
    ],
    [
      'junit',
      { outputFile: 'playwright_results/playwright_report/reports.xml' },
    ],
  ],
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    baseURL: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,


    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    // Setup project
    {
      name: 'setup', testMatch: /.*\.setup\.js/
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { 
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        // Use prepared auth state.
        storageState: 'playwright/.auth/user.json',
      },
      dependencies: ['setup']
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { 
        ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
        // Use prepared auth state.
        storageState: 'playwright/.auth/user.json',
      },
      dependencies: ['setup']
    },
```

example of what is written in playwright/.auth/user.json when tests are run locally

```
{
  "cookies": [],
  "origins": [
    {
      "origin": "http://localhost:8080",
      "localStorage": [
        {
          "name": "header",
          "value": "3c9cf469144b01c34eb09dfb9fbfa09b19dc4139"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```